# MySQL REPLACE in an auto incremented row

Tags: mysql, replace, innodb

Let say I have a MySQL table which contains three columns: `id`, `a` and `b` and the column named `id` is an `AUTO INCREMENT` field. If I pass a query like the following to MySQL, it will works fine:

```
REPLACE INTO `table` (`id`, `a`, `b`) VALUES (1, 'A', 'B')
```

But if I skip the field `id` it will no longer works, which is expected.

I want to know if there is a way to `ignore` some fields in the `REPLACE` query. So the above query could be something like this:

```
REPLACE INTO `table` (`a`, `b`) VALUES ('A', 'B')
```

**Why do I need such a thing?**

Sometimes I need to check a database with a `SELECT` query to see if a row exists or not. If it is exists then I need to `UPDATE` the existing row, otherwise I need to `INSERT` a new row. I'm wondering if I could achieve a similar result (but not same) with a single `REPLACE` query.

Why it couldn't be the *same* result? Simply because `REPLACE` will `DELETE` the existing row and will `INSERT` a new row, which will *lose* the current `primary key` and will increase the *auto incremented* values. In contrast, in an `UPDATE` query, `primary key` and the `AI` fields will be untouched.

MySQL [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

Comment: I can't understand your question. What actually you wanna do?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP Are you familiar with MySQL `REPLACE`?

Comment: @Mahdi- Please provide table data before REPLACE query and your expected output after REPLACE query. I'll try to give you the solution

Comment: 1) share proper table schema. 2) That's not how you're supposed to use replace. 3) use replace only when you know `primary key` values.

Comment: @Mahdi -i'm still not clear about your question. Whatever data is in the table it should be replaced by ('A','B') right?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP The row which contains `1,A,A` should be replaced by `2,A,B`. I think it's not that confusing, is it?

Comment: @Mahdi- Just delete all contents of the table then use insert query.

Comment: @FathahRehmanP Oh, man, come on ... Why I should delete all the data in a table to insert a new row???

Comment: Should I say that `those row is just a sample`?

Comment: @Mahdi - suppose your table contain three rows before REPLACE
(1, A, A)
(2, A, B)
(3, A, C)
Then you used REPLACE INTO `table` (`a`,`b`) VALUES ('A','B')
query . what is your expected result?

Comment: See answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901769/reuse-rows-in-mysql-table-without-auto-incrementing?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- That's not how you're supposed to use replace.
- use replace only when you know `primary key` values.

Manual:

> Note that unless the table has a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index, using a
>   REPLACE statement makes no sense. It becomes equivalent to INSERT,
>   because there is no index to be used to determine whether a new row
>   duplicates another.

Comment: What if we have a unique index, say column `A`, and I want to do `REPLACE INTO `table` (`a`, `b`) VALUES ('A', 'B')`? Is this a good use case?

Answer (score 3):

What if you have multiple rows that match the fields?

Consider adding a key that you can match on and use `INSERT IGNORE.. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. The way INSERT IGNORE works is slightly different from REPLACE.

INSERT IGNORE is very fast but can have some invisible side effects.

`INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Which has fewer side effects but is probably much slower, especially for MyISAM, heavy write loads, or heavily indexed tables.

For more details on the side effects, see: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/548570/1301627

Using INSERT IGNORE seems to work well for very fast lookup MyISAM tables with few columns (maybe just a VARCHAR field).

For example,

```
create table cities (
    city_id int not null auto_increment,
    city varchar(200) not null,
    primary key (city_id),
    unique key city (city))
    engine=myisam default charset=utf8;

insert ignore into cities (city) values ("Los Angeles");
```

In this case, repeatedly re-inserting "Los Angeles" will not result in any actual changes to the table at all and will prevent a new auto_increment ID from being generated, which can help prevent ID field exhaustion (using up all the available auto_increment range on heavily churned tables).

For even more speed, use a small hash like spooky hash before inserting and use that for a separate unique key column and then the varchar won't get indexed at all.

Comment: Also, note: if an insert is ignored, the value from `last_insert_id()` is undefined. Thus, instead of using that, you'll have to do `select city_id from cities where city="Los Angeles"` after your `insert ignore` to make sure you get a good ID value (if you need it). Even so, this will still be much faster versus to `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` since (almost always) writes are slower than reads. (On Innodb, use a transaction if desired.)

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please add a comment explaining why you feel this is an invalid point.

Comment: In Postgresql, this is called UPSERT.