# INSERT/REPLACE INTO...SELECT; duplicate problems

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-into

Events from my database `bd_yellowbox` should be added to the database `groupofficecom`. The data of one event in `bd_yellowbox` is stored in three attributes tables `element`, `actions`, and `actionsparam`. All three tables have one column in common, `ID_ELEMENT`. The column has the same value in all three tables for one data point.

The data of one event in `groupofficecom` is stored in two tables, `cal_events` and `cf_cal_events`. The primary key of `cal_events` is `id` and is auto incremented. The primary key of `cf_cal_events` is `model_id` and is **NOT** auto incremented.

```
cf_cal_events.model_id = cal_events.id
```

The two databases are linked through a column in the table `cf_cal_events`:

```
cf_cal_events.col_10 = bd_yellowbox.element.ID_ELEMENT
```

Here's my original code:

```
REPLACE INTO groupofficecom.cal_events (data1,data2)
VALUES ('1','Tom Hanks')

REPLACE INTO groupofficecom.cf_cal_events (model_id, col_10)
SELECT groupofficecom.cal_events.id, bd_yellowbox.element.ID_ELEMENT
FROM bd_yellowbox.element, groupofficecom.cal_events
WHERE bd_yellowbox.element.ID_ELEMENT=bd_yellowbox.actions.ID_ELEMENT
AND bd_yellowbox.element.ID_ELEMENT=bd_yellowbox.actionsparam.ID_ELEMENT;
```

Problem #1: the insertion of data in `cf_cal_events` is resulting in one event being inserted as multiple events with different IDs.

Problem #2: when I re-execute the query, the events are re-inserted into both tables as new events. This creates new `id`s because of the AUTO_INCREMENT of cf_events.id, which prevents changed events from being updated in the `bd_yellowbox` database.

THANK YOU ALL!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem #0:** You still haven't provided the https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. And are you sure that your current code snippet will even execute?

**Problem #1**

I think that this problem has to do with the structure of your database.
As I suppose:

One `yellow_box.element` can have multiple `yellow_box.action` - it is logical that one element can be acted upon many times.

One  `yellow_box.action` can have multiple `yellow_box.action_param` - it is less obvious and may not be so

It means that if we have:

```
CREATE TABLE yellow_box.element
(
    ElementId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Description nvachar(128)
)

CREATE TABLE yellow_box.actions
(
    ActionId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ElementId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES yellow_box.element(ElementId),
    Description nvachar(128)
)

CREATE TABLE yellow_box.actions_param
(
    ActionParamId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ActionId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES yellow_box.actions(ActionId),
    Description nvachar(128)
)
```

With 1 element, two actions on this element, each with two actions_param, how many rows will be returned by

```
SELECT element.ElementId, action.ActionId, param.ActionParamId 
FROM yellow_box.element AS element
    INNER JOIN yellow_box.actions AS action
    ON action.ElementId = element.ElementId
    INNER JOIN yellow_box.actions_param AS param
    ON param.ActionId = action.ActionId
```

It will be 4 rows.

That's from where all those duplicate rows come - your joined(just using the WHERE clause)  those tables increasing the result set, but never used any columns form them - that's why you've seen complete duplicates:

```
SELECT "I am the duplicate" 
FROM yellow_box.element AS element
    INNER JOIN yellow_box.actions AS action
    ON action.ElementId = element.ElementId
    INNER JOIN yellow_box.actions_param AS param
    ON param.ActionId = action.ActionId
```

Will return 4 rows with "I am the duplicate"

**Problem #2**

REPLACE INTO doesn't go well with auto incrementing primary keys [MySQL REPLACE in an auto incremented row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217067/mysql-replace-in-an-auto-incremented-row), [PHP mySQL - Insert new record into table with auto-increment on primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492145/php-mysql-insert-new-record-into-table-with-auto-increment-on-primary-key).

You could try the DEFAULT placeholder on primary key column on replace:

```
REPLACE INTO yellow_box.actions_param(ActionId, Description)
VALUES (100, "Original")

REPLACE INTO yellow_box.actions_param yellow_box.actions_param(ActionParamId, ActionId, Description)
VALUES (DEFAULT, 100, "Original")
```

But I am not sure that it will work

or you could try to use the update statement http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm to directly update the rows using their primary key value to identify them.

Comment: In fact I agree the database isn't very well, but I can't change anything, because both databases are for programs, and I only need to add events from one to another. It's a one direction INSERT relationship

Comment: But maybe you could try to rectify the problem #0? Because otherwise  I don't know how to help you.

Comment: You mean rewrite the problem with more generalizing?

Comment: If you can't find a problem - divide, simplify, try from scratch. Because some problems may be very difficult to find in the full solution.

Comment: ELEMENT_ID is ,like I said in the question, the primary key of all three tables `elements`, `actions`, and `actionsparam` in `bd_yellowbox`.
and the `WHERE` clause is fine, it solved the duplicates problem, but the problems are:
1. I can't
    INSERT INTO groupofficecom.cf_cal_events (model_id)
    SELECT groupofficecom.cal_events.id
    FROM groupofficecom.cal_events
2. I can't link `groupofficecom.cal_events.id = groupofficecom.cf_cal_events.model_id` with `groupofficecom.cf_cal_events.col_10 = bd_yellowbox.element.ELEMENT_ID`

Comment: Try to create  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You will better understand yout database(it is always a good thing to do) and provide a snippet that anyone can use to repeat your problem on their machines.

Comment: I'm creating an SQL fiddle, then I'll update the link to the question.
Thank you!